# Where do electric circuit topologies come from?

Tags: circuit-design, topology

The question is pretty straight forward but allow me to expand.

If not clear, by circuit topologies I mean connections between circuit elements/blocks.

What branch of mathematics deals with this? Do electrical engineers study such stuff, in what domain?

The reason for asking this question is, I see circuit designs that use a specific circuit topology but not how topologies are derived. Please shed some light on this.

P.S: I'm an EE student so I do have a rough-idea that a lot of it comes down to R&D of such stuff. I'm more interested in abstract tools (i.e mathematical ideas in layman language) that revolves around such stuff.

Comment: From empirical experience in a lot of cases. Looking at old books (I mean from the 1920s on) you can see some wild topologies that by the 1930s were abandoned for ones that worked better. Some of those still remain : superhet radios, push pull amplifiers (adapted to transistors) and so on. Starts all over again with digital logic around WW2... and so on.

Comment: If I asked you "I see different types of designs for engines, like piston engines, rotary engines, and turbines, but how are they derived? What branch of mathematics deals with this?" What would be your answer for me? You make it sound like you think people came up with circuit topologies axiomatically without ever leaving a piece of paper the same way a mathematicians come up with stuff. People come up with ideas based on what they know, try them out, and if they work analyze and refine them. And the most successful ones become widespread and become "topologies".

Comment: It only seems that they "derived" it mathematically because the people who did are really really smart with lots of experience, so when there is a big knowledge gap between you and them, you can't see the "pieces" of the circuit so you can't see the steps involved and the potential variations. If you know enough to breakdown the sections in the topology and what they do it is a lot easier to see the incremental steps. You also don't see all the topologies that were not successful which show that was not a clear cut logical progression.

Comment: Calculusnoob, It's not all that complicated. Devices have dominant mathematics associated with them. They don't do what we want. They do what they want to do, instead. By examination of what they do and examination of what we want them to do for us, we find ways to apply other devices (resistors, capacitors, inductors, etc) that also have their own math functions to create the math we want to see. For example, we know from the equations about temperature dependence. And we can use our imaginations about other parts and places to connect them that might help. Work the math and see. Then build.

Comment: Calculusnoob, Early examples will use fewer ideas to get there. People will note remaining problems and then use their imagination to find a simple (or complex) modification to improve the overall situation. Some of these become standard fare (because they are good enough and cheap enough, etc.) Some are truly genius. A shockingly good example that isn't hard to follow, once seen, is Michael Wyatt's Cascode Peaking Current Source. So sometimes these things are inspirational. Most, though, are of the "obvious improvement" variety.

Comment: Calculusnoob, And before you imagine that these ideas originated in electronics, let me tell you that in most ways they do NOT. They often arrive from mechanical ideas or mathematical ideas that are just cross-pollinated into electronics by someone(s). Modern electronics just makes it a lot easier to do more complex things in smaller spaces, with less power, lower cost, etc. But to be honest? Many ideas were brought in from elsewhere and simply plunked down and made to work in a new space. Like many things in life.

Comment: (For those interested in Wyatt's design that I mentioned, see [here](https://www.edn.com/peaking-current-source-has-high-rejection/).)

Comment: @BrianDrummond Nice..Can you share some relevant resources on the stuff you mentioned? Some books/design notes/application notes etc.

Comment: @jonk Thank you for your kind explanation.

Comment: John Scott-Taggart "Manual of modern radio" (1933) is a good example. Jonk's mention of a Cascode circuit is interesting : tetrode valves (improved into pentodes) did essentially the cascode's job in a single valve. But you can't just add extra grids in a transistor, so the (2 transistor) cascode was developed to imitate them.

Answer (score 5):

Ans:  inventors create them.  From nothing.  Then everyone else hooks them together as "building blocks" to create more complicated systems.   Then sometimes years later, mathematicians work out the rigorous theoretical descriptions.

Simple example: look up the history of the Hartley Oscillator, the Colpitts, Dynatron, Clapp, Armstrong, or perhaps the vacuum-tube differential amplifier "long-tailed pair."  Or even the Klystron uWave amp.  Oscillators were invented before 1890, with math description only happening in 1921.

(It's like asking, where do new symphonies come from, where do famous poems come from, how was John Lennon (or ANY sane human) able to write the music that he did? )

PS

How is "technical creativity" performed?  Mathematician Henri Poincaré was one of the early investigators.  He discovered that he could come up with amazing breakthroughs ...out of nothing.   They just appeared in his head, in great detail, fully formed.  Poincaré became curious about this, and asked top-level colleagues in other math departments.  It turned out that everyone was doing this!  (They all kept it secret, thinking that they were the only ones who were "cheating" in this way.)

They weren't solving puzzles.  Instead, they were taking long showers, or perhaps listening to music. Micro-dosing LSD, like Watson and Crick.  Getting into slightly-altered mental states, trying to trigger Genius insights.  (Poincaré made his greatest discovery when leaving for vacation, stepping onto a streetcar.)

In "Science and Method," Poincaré gives the secret formula:

1. work on a problem for weeks, months, and be utterly defeated.  You've failed.
2. give up.
3. work on something else.  Or better yet, go on vacation.   Or take a long night-time highway drive, like Cary Mullis or Atanasoff did.
4. suddenly in an instant, your brain is filled with an immense amount of detailed information, all from nowhere.
5. Pull over to the side of the road, get out your little notebook or stack of napkins, and spend hours scribbling it all down, before it all goes away again.

Many discoveries (including many totally new circuit ideas) come from imagination: "flashes of inspiration."  But they don't come without lots of work, since the "creative leaps" seem often to be the resolution of a major personal failure, after some huge amounts of background research which, lacking the breakthrough idea, was all going to be wasted.

PPS

Me, I think some of these "flashes" come from temporal paradoxes.  If you're to be the creator of a famous invention. then if only you could see into your own future, you could steal the idea ...from yourself.  Then build it and claim to have invented it.  But who then was the actual inventor?  Why you, of course!  See the RAH sf story "All You Zombies" ...or go and listen to "I'm my own grandpa."

PPPS

The late Ralph Hartley was my roommate at the U. Rochester.
(No, not the original Oscillator Ralph.  This was his grandson.)

PPPPS

Speaking of topology, how could any normal human ever come up with the song I'M MY OWN GRANDPA?  Where did the original idea come from?  Outa freakin' nowhere?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SnI963ZzgY

Answer (score -1):

Inventing solutions to challenges is how humans survive and thrive.

Immerse in the topic, all aspects, all abstractions, all maths, all lab results you can find or generate.

Slowly question everything, in everyway. Let the brain muse over all these different aspects.

People call this "artistic", but you are training the brain, the connections, the synapses, to constantly attempt to fire as various correlations of pulse_trains occur.

Find a new phenomena? Learn it, and think how it may affect all the other aspects of your system. Think about everything, slowly, slowly. Go slowly, so the new synapses have time to be strengthened.

At various times, I've had engineers come to me with "I am losing sleep about my current project." I tell them "As a shareholder, I like that. Losing sleep tells me you have intensely focused on the constraints, the possibilities, the bottlenecks, the interdependencies, and your brain is actively searching all that space of possible tradeoffs ---- to find an acceptable solution, even if some innovation is required."

I continue "At this point, tho management has proclaimed this mindset to be ARTISTIC, you have **IMMERSED** your neurons in the topic. In constantly churning thru the issues as you try to sleep, you are triggering a subconscious exploration of the search_space. Just have patience with your (sleepless) brain, and go with the flow, letting the mind race thru the variables, the topologies, the needed behaviors. Trust you brain; you have trained it; now be patient."

Notice you don't just READ something once, and then expect the inventions to occur.

You must actively LEARN, and actively strive to consider all possible interactions. This LEARNING is a very active time, a very focused time.